# How to calculate total for every row?

Tags: angular

I have this:

```
 <div class="first-row" *ngFor="let key of Object.keys(channels); let i=index">
          <h5> {{key}}</h5>
          <div class="second-row-inputs" *ngFor="let d of data;let i = index" [style.width.%]="width">
            <table-td [field]="d" [data]="data" (eventEmit)="eventEmit()"></table-td>
          </div>
</div>
```

My `table-td` component :

```
<total-td #total *ngIf="field.code=='total'" [data]="data"></total-td>
```

My `total-td` component:

```
<input class='input' type="text" [(ngModel)]="total">
```

In total i have this metod:

```
  calculate() {
    this.data.map((a: any) => { this.total += Number(a.value); });
  }
```

In my table-td component i have :

```
@ViewChild('total') public total: TotalComponent;
```

but when i do this :

```
this.total.calculate();
```

Im getting undefined. Any suggestion how can i calculate total?

```
data: [{ code: 'JAN', displayName: 'January', value: 0 }, { code: 'FEB', displayName: 'February', value: 0 }, { code: 'MAR', displayName: 'March', value: 0 }, { code: 'total', displayName: 'Total', value: 0 }]
```

Comment: can u show output on `console.log(this.data);` in calculate method?

Comment: i cannot access to calulate method from parent  its undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the `ngIf` which is causing the view to be undefined.  You can use `ViewChildren` instead of `ViewChild`.

```
@ViewChildren('total') public total: TotalComponent;
```

**Another Trick** is to use `[hidden]` instead of `*ngIf`:

```
<total-td #total [hidden]="field.code=='total'" [data]="data"></total-td>
```